# Is there a way to set object parameter value to empty string if object does not exist in php

Tags: php

Is there a way to set object parameter value to empty string or null if object does not exist instead of fatal error?

Lets say i have this in my view:

```
<div> <?php $car->name; ?> </div
```

And there is a chance that car is empty object in some cases. 
I just could write my own function that checks object and return object parameter or empty string, but i want to know if there is a default way to do this.

Another way would be use shorthand if statement, as in

```
($car) ? $car->name : "";
```

but it is too long to but in view IMHO.

Comment: If your object is a method and not stdClass, you can use [__call](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call) method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few different options

The long way is using one of the following functions in an if statement:

- isset
- empty

example

```
if(!isset($car->name)) {
    return 'No car';
}
```

using empty

```
if(empty($car->name)) {
    return 'No car';
}
```

Or you can combine both if you really wanted.

You can also use them in shorthand as you have done above or using the isset and or empty functions.

If you are using PHP version 7 you can use a new feature that shipped with it called Null coalescing operator (??)

Example:

```
echo $car->name ?? 'No car';
```

> It returns its first operand if it exists and is not NULL; otherwise it returns its second operand.

I am running PHP7 and use it daily!